# How can I solve this problem without rename images. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 (1)'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, training-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cInhf.png)

How can I solve this problem without rename images.
I named them are "User.1 (1)". By rename much photos in once.(F2).
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please write a [minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't post images when you can post code.

Comment: By the way the message just says that `1 (1)` cannot (obviously) converted to an int